# How to split a line with tab in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a file separated with tab:

```
04/20/13,22:54:08   10  17h ADC 10  11123456545644  0
```

I wrote this snippet to read this file:

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');
var fs = require('fs');

lineReader.eachLine('foo.txt', function(line, last, cb) {
      var splitLine = line.split('\t');
      console.log(splitLine[0]);

      if (last) {
            cb(false); // stop reading
      } else {
        cb();
      }
    });
```

The output is this:

```
04/20/13,22:54:08
10
17h ADC
10
11123456545644
0
```

How I can pick up the info separated?

For example: with splitLine(0) I'm expecting only the timeStamp, but it prints the entire row.

How is it possible?

Comment: have you tried printing the whole content of line before splitting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of **substring** you can get the **timestamp**.
`console.log(splitLine[0].substring(10));`